# Remove values of an entire row java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a String array that has 10 rows and 4 columns that holds contact information.  If the user wants to remove a contact, but maintain 10 rows and 4 columns - without using lists in any fashion - how is this done?  For instance:

```
contacts[0][0] = fName; //Charlie
        contacts[0][1] = lName; //Brown
        contacts[0][2] = pNum; //(309)555-1212
        contacts[0][3] = age1; //10
        contacts[1][0] = fName1; //Sally
        contacts[1][1] = lName; //Brown
        contacts[1][2] = pNum; //(309)555-1212
        contacts[1][3] = age3; //8
```

Now the user wants to remove Charlie Brown from contacts, and move all other rows to fill in the empty space, maintaining a total of 10 rows and 4 columns.

The lastest attempt is:

```
private void removeContact(String[][] contacts)
    {   
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lName;
        String fName;
        int fIndex;
        int lIndex;
        System.out.println("What is the first name of the contact to remove?");
        fName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the last name of the contact to remove?");
        lName = input.nextLine();
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {               
                if (contacts[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(fName) && contacts[i][1].equalsIgnoreCase(lName))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("That contact was not found.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (found) 
            {
                contacts[i][0] = null;
                contacts[i][1] = null;
                contacts[i][2] = null;
                contacts[i][3] = null;
                return;
            }                                   
        }
    }
```

This works great if you only want to remove Charlie Brown, but for any other row...it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You will have to code a for-loop to shift the elements if you want to use arrays.

To achieve this:

```
int ind; //the index you'd like to remove.
for(int i = ind + 1; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i - 1] = array[i];
}
//set last value to nulls or something.
```

Consider an ArrayList: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html It'll do all the shifting for you.

Also, you might want to make `People` objects and make your array (or ArrayList) one of `People`. This way you won't have to keep track of attributes of your contacts with arbitrary numbers and can have more readable and re-usable code.

Comment: Not allowed to use lists of any type.  Must maintain the array of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can move all the rows and replace the last one.

```
 System.arrayCopy(contacts, 1, contacts, 0, contacts.length-1);
 Arrays.fill(contacts[contacts.length-1] = new String[4], "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order does not matter here, it would be more efficient if you simply copy the last element in the array over the position being deleted and reduce the size variable by one (I am assuming you are keeping the count of address book entries in the array in a variable).